# Django models: unexpected behaviour

Tags: django, django-models

I have such views:

```
def finish_creation(request, pre_id):
    pre_post = PrePost.objects.get(pk = pre_id)
    if pre_id == pre_post.id:
        this = Post.objects.create(
            author = pre_post.author,
            title = pre_post.title,
            text = pre_post.text
        )

        this.pswd = some_password
        this.save()
        pre_post.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(this.get_absolute_url())
```

Explanation: unauthorized user (author) can write posts on site, but first creates some temporary pre_post in database and sends email to author with link in it to activate (transfer temporary pre_post to permanent post). After follow a link creates Post from PrePost elements, PrePost deletes from database and user automatically redirects to his publicated post.

But there is **error**: `Pre_Post matching query does not exist.`

But everything else is OK:

1) Post creates perfectly,

2) Pre_post deletes perfectly,

and only `return HttpResponseRedirect(this.get_absolute_url())` doesn't work...

However, error page refers on first line in views `pre_post = PrePost.objects.get(pk = pre_id)`

How could it be?

Thanks.

**EDITED:**

But when I didn't delete `pre_post` everything worked fine as expected (except deletion of pre_post). What's wrong with that delete()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really bad design to begin with. You shouldn't be moving data from one table to another to publish it. Simply add a field to the one model. For example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then, you can write a custom manager to pull only approved posts:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def approved(self):
        return self.filter(approved=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PostManager()
```

Finally, in your views and templates, just use `Post.objects.approved()`, instead of `Post.objects.all()`. So only approved posts will ever be shown on site.

You can then only show the `approved` field in your forms when the user is a superuser, or whatever other designation you want, and only they will be able to mark it as approved.

You could also do this many other ways, such as a "Published" status that only superusers could set, etc., but this is the general idea.

**EDIT** The problem with your current code is that there is always a possibility that an object won't exist. You must account for that possibility by *always* wrapping calls to `get` in `try...except` blocks:

```
try:
    pre_post = PrePost.objects.get(pk = pre_id)
except PrePost.DoesNotExist:
    # Do something or...
    pass
else:
    # object exists; you can do stuff with it here.
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if I need to do so, what can be wrong in my code?